# How to preserve photo square aspect ratio in facebook share with link (similar to instagram)

Tags: ios, facebook, share, facebook-opengraph, photo

I am trying to create a mobile app for photo sharing similar to instagram like this:

[image]

Notice 2 things:

- Original image aspect ratio of the square photo is preserved (nothing is cropped out)
- Link "Instagram" points to the instagram page of the photo
  https://instagram.com/p/72U--QKh5EDiTeBDvqSpKqltAkgog3HwaWqGI0/

I am really not clear and based on the documentation from here (checkout point no.4):
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

```
"We've also redesigned link page posts so that the aspect ratio for images is the same across desktop and mobile News Feed. Try to keep your images as close to 1.91:1 aspect ratio as possible to display the full image in News Feed without any cropping."
```

So it says that best is to make sure the shared image is 1.91:1 to prevent anything cropped out.

In practice with Instagram is possible but documentation says otherwise. Can someone provide a clear guideline/doc on how to share a "square" photo and preserving the aspect ratio displayed in facebook timeline (and provide a specific link to the photo page)? If answer with code for web/ios/etc would also be great.

Comment: Since Instagram is owned By Facebook, I think we can assume they can use a special post format that is not available to other, 3rd parties. You will have to work with the aspect ratio of 1.91:1, or accept that your photos will be shown as a small, cropped square if the ratio of your photos differs much.

Comment: Thats what we are thinking along as well but is this a definite answer ? I cant truly find any info on this. Is there someone who knows in detail on this or attempted to investigate properly on this. Are there similar apps other than instagram that can achieve this ? Can you up the vote for this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the discussion in FB Dev Community (mentioned by FB guys themselves), it is clear that it is not allowed even they not officially stating it.

https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/961186750591506

Facebook owns Instagram, they have monopolistic behaviour over how Facebook gives access to Instagram.

In wish of some fairness, openness and anti-monopolistic behaviour of facebook, If you guys really wish to have this feature, vote up more on this and put in comments to support it, hope they will hear out on such a critical feature needed for photo-sharing apps (just like instagram)